# problem initializing a custom class (UIImageView may not respond to '-alloc')

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, alloc

I have an issue for this line

```
ball* balle = [[ball alloc] initWithPNGFileName:ballPath andGame:game andCGRect:CGRectMake( 200, 100, 16, 16 )] ;
```

the issue is ' ball undeclared' with warning: 'UIImageView' may not respond to '-alloc' and warning: no '-initWithPNGFileName:andGame:andCGRect:' method found

Here's the method:

```
-(id) initWithPNGFileName:(NSString *) filename andGame: (Game*) game andCGRect: (CGRect) imagerect_ {  
    [super init];

    CGDataProviderRef provider;
    CFStringRef path;
    CFURLRef url;


    const char *filenameAsChar = [filename cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]; //CFStringCreateWithCString n'accepte pas de NSString

    path = CFStringCreateWithCString (NULL, filenameAsChar, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, path, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, NO);
    CFRelease(path);
    provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithURL (url);
    CFRelease (url);
    image = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider (provider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    CGDataProviderRelease (provider);

    imageRect = imagerect_ ;

    [game addToDraw: self] ;
    [game addToTimer : self] ;

    return self ;

}


-(void) draw: (CGContextRef) gc
{
    CGContextDrawImage (gc, imageRect, image );
}
```

I don't understand why UIImageView can't be allocated and why I have no '-initWithPNGFileName:andGame:andCGRect:' method found

Thanks

Comment: Hi.. Can you post the `.h` file of `ball` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you provide it seems that you have an instance of `UIImageView` called `ball`. Are you sure your Class is called `ball` (Class names should begin with a capital letter, by the way) and it's `.h` - file is properly included?

Some background information: `alloc` is a class method, you don't send it to an instance - it's signature is something like `+ (id) alloc;` (mind the plus here!) Basically, the warning says that you try to invoke the *instance method* alloc on your object, which would have the signature `- (id) alloc;` (mind the minus here!), if it existed (which is most probably not the case). Therefore, the compiler recognizes `ball` not as a class name, but as an instance of `UIImageView`, which  - as the warning indicates - may not respond to `- (id) alloc;` . 
By default, the compiler assumes that unknown methods return an instance of `id` (and not of `ball` as you expected), this is why it warns you that it can't find a method called `-initWithPNGFileName:andGame:andCGRect` for this object.

Comment: .h is well included. The fact that UIImageView is named as the class generates a problem?

Comment: I have updated my answer with some more background information. Basically, the compiler does not know that you are adressing the UIImageView and not the class 'ball'. Renaming the UIImageView should solve your issue.

Comment: Could you provide some more code around the line where you try to alloc/init the ball?

Comment: I got it, I changet the method providing the image for the object. Thank you